# Javascript\Jquery mouse cursor - Inconsistencies when hovering items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to replace the mouse cursor on my website with a custom one, composed of two elements:

- a cursor;
- a trail that follows the cursor and lags behind it.

Doing that with jquery is extremely easy.

1) You hide the default cursor in CSS:

```
html, body {cursor:none;}
```

2) You create two different divs (one for the cursor itself and one for the trail) and style them:

```
<div id="mouse_cursor" class="mouse_cursor"></div>
<div id="mouse_trail" class="mouse_trail"></div>
```

3) You create the logic for each one of them:

```
function moveCursor(e) {
    $('#mouse_cursor').css({'left' : e.pageX,'top' : e.pageY });
}
$(window).on('mousemove', moveCursor);

function moveTrail(e) {
    TweenMax.to('#mouse_trail', 0.35, {
    css: {left: e.pageX,top: e.pageY},
    ease:SlowMo.easeIn
    }
)};
$(window).on('mousemove', moveTrail);
```

(In my case the trail effect is made using Greensock's GSAP).

Now... this works perfectly as long as the cursor style isn't changed. Here's a fiddle, for your reference: https://jsfiddle.net/collederfomento/jvy1zfg8/27/

---

I'd like to change the style of the cursor once it hovers specific elements, however, and that's where I am encountering a few issues.

The way I have attempted to do that is the following:

1) Create a function bound to the mouseenter \ mouseover events that adds a class to the cursor if it's hovering the element:

```
$(".hover").bind( "mouseenter mouseover", function() {
    $("#mouse_cursor").addClass("mouse_cursor_hover");
});
```

2) ... and then a second function that removes the class once the cursor is not hovering the element anymore:

```
$(".hover").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#mouse_cursor").removeClass("mouse_cursor_hover");
});
```

3) Lastly, of course, I added the style for the "hover" cursor:

```
.mouse_cursor_hover {width:300px;height:300px;}
```

As you can see in this fiddle ( https://jsfiddle.net/collederfomento/z4e1qjbc/13/ ) the hover event is not firing properly, and the mouse cursor flickers.

I have tried several other approaches (using Javascript event listener rather than the above mentioned functions, using the css property rather than toggling a class, etc.) but they all behave in the same way.

What's curious is that if I remove the functions that make the cursors move, then the hover event is handled flawlessly. I believe the combination of the two functions is causing the issue, but I have no clue why (or how to solve it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cursor and the trail elements are interfering with the hover events. Even though they are at a high z-index, the browser still has to take them into account to figure out which element is actually getting hovered. The mouse cursor is still going over them after all, since they are not a “real” cursor, but actual elements positioned in that place.

Adding `pointer-events` none to both of them seems to fix the issue for the most part (checked in Chrome and Firefox, in both it seemed to significantly improve), so please give that a try:

```
.mouse_cursor,
.mouse_trail {
  pointer-events:none; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aur39py4/1/

I am assuming that you are not going to need any sort of hover effect on the cursor and trail themselves, so setting `pointer-events:none` should not have any adverse effects on the rest of what you’re doing on the page.

Comment: Oh man! That's amazing! I'll check the support on a few other browsers \ OSs, just to be on the safe side, but on a general level this is a great solution! Thank you so much!