# How to make a mouse trail with CSS/JS so that elements are still clickable?

Tags: javascript, css

I‘d like to have a mouse trail when the mouse moves. The trail should be built out of small icons/images loosing capacity over time. (for simplicity I removed the capacity transition code in the demo) I tried to have this effect, creating a grid which lays on top of all other elements. This grid consists of small divs with a background-image. The opacity of every div is set to 0. Visually the solution works, but the elements on the whole page are not clickable any more. How is it possible to have the same visual effect and yet all elements on the page are still clickable?

I tried to make the z-index of clickable elements higher than the z-index of the grid-elements. The elements are then clickable. But then the trail effect does not show on them, which is not what it should be like.

I researched for a solution and came across these pages/tutorials below, but they don't offer a solution to my problem:

https://medium.com/@dailyfire/cursor-trails-3-simple-css-tricks-to-add-to-any-website-part-1-64750798583c

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfpRZ2t_BrQ

[Javascript\Jquery mouse cursor - Inconsistencies when hovering items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55454541/javascript-jquery-mouse-cursor-inconsistencies-when-hovering-items)

```js
const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
const mouseMovementContainer = document.createElement("div");

mouseMovementContainer.setAttribute("id", "mouseMovementContainer");
mouseMovementContainer.classList.add("mouseMovement");

body.insertBefore(mouseMovementContainer, body.firstChild);

createNewGrid();

function createNewGrid () {
    for(let i = 0; i <= 1000; i++){
        const square = createOneSquare();
        mouseMovementContainer.appendChild(square);
    }
}

function createOneSquare () {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("square");
    return div;
}
```

```css
a{
  font-size: 40px;
}

.mouseMovement {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.square {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: url("https://icon-library.com/images/fire-icon-free/fire-icon-free-1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0;
}

.square:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Go to Google!!!!</a>
```

Comment: Add `pointer-events: none;` to the elements in question (CSS).

Comment: Duplicate: [Make overlapping div "not clickable" so that content below can be accessed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700051/make-overlapping-div-not-clickable-so-that-content-below-can-be-accessed)

Comment: @ChrisG Setting pointer events does not work since the mousemove is also removed

Comment: @mplungjan In this very specific case maybe, but creating a mouse trail only requires assigning that event to the document, doesn't it?

Comment: @ChrisG what do you mean by assigning that event to the document? If I understand your suggestion right, then still it does not work. Because added elements to the document will be on top of the document and the trail will still not show when hovering over them.

Comment: cc @mplungjan Here's my solution: https://jsfiddle.net/ky6orLf3/

Comment: @ChrisG: thanks that is exactly what I wanted. I don't understand the code of your solution at the moment. But I am going to take some more time to understand how you did it.

Comment: Here's a version with comments: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/a7vrp4cg/ (there's even a better way where the divs actually move, the current version only works due to the high number of trails divs and small interval delay)

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you so much, that is very helpful with the comments. =)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the z-index works

Setting pointer events does not work since the mousemove is also removed

```
.mouseMovement {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  z-index: -1;  
}
```

```js
const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
const mouseMovementContainer = document.createElement("div");

mouseMovementContainer.setAttribute("id", "mouseMovementContainer");
mouseMovementContainer.classList.add("mouseMovement");

body.insertBefore(mouseMovementContainer, body.firstChild);

createNewGrid();

function createNewGrid () {
    for(let i = 0; i <= 1000; i++){
        const square = createOneSquare();
        mouseMovementContainer.appendChild(square);
    }
}

function createOneSquare () {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("square");
    return div;
}
```

```css
a {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.mouseMovement {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  z-index: -1;  
}

.square {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: url("https://icon-library.com/images/fire-icon-free/fire-icon-free-1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0;

}

.square:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Go to Google!!!!</a>
```

Comment: Yes setting the z-index is kind of a solution. I already figured that out. But then the trail effect doesn't show on the clickable elements any more. In this small example seems not like a big deal. But I have e.g. also a video gallery where the whole video elements should be clickable. So the trail effect would be only seen on small areas with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `pointer-events:none;` allows you to click "through" the div to the content below.

Comment: but turns off all the trails in this case

Comment: That's unfortunate. Hope one of the other solutions works for you.

Comment: Not my question

Comment: Yeah the click works with this solution, but as said before the trail effect isn't there anymore